# Transfer a PCM file from a server to an app via node.js

Tags: android, node.js, pcm

I need to transfer a PCM file from a server to my Android app.
I need to know:

a. How to transfer the file from the server side with node.js?

b. How to read the file from my Android app?

This is what I currently did, and when I try to play the file from the app, it's only a partial part of the file:

On the server side -

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs'); 
var filePath = path.join('C:\\tmp', 'prompt.pcm');
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);   
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
readStream.pipe(res);
return;
}
```

On the app's side:

```
// Created here an HTTP client and request (didn't write the code, it's OK)...
response = client.execute(request);
InputStream is = (InputStream)(response.getEntity().getContent());
PlayShortAudioFileViaAudioTrack(is);    

    private void PlayShortAudioFileViaAudioTrack(InputStream is)
{
    //Reading the file    
    byte[] byteData = null; 
    byteData = new byte[300000];
    is.read( byteData );
    is.close(); 
    // Set and push to audio track
    int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(22000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT); 
    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, intSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM); 
    if (at!=null) { 
        at.play();
        // Write the byte array to the track
        at.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length); 
        at.stop();
        at.release();
    }
    else
        Log.d("TCAudio", "audio track is not initialised ");

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why only a small portion of the file is being played?

Thanks!

Comment: `byteData = new byte[300000];
    is.read( byteData );` Why 300000 ? You should check the return value of is.read() as it may be less than asked.

Comment: You are write, but in this case this is not the problem, as this is larger than the size of the file. Anyway, how can I check the return value of is.read()? Thanks.

Comment: int nbytesread = is.read(byteData );